# Assign a object to the pointer the node is referring

Tags: python-3.4

```py
class BinarySearchTree:

    def __init__(self, value=None, left=None, right=None):
        self.value = value
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

    def insert(self, value) -> bool:
        current_node = self

        while current_node is not None:
            if current_node.value < value:
                current_node = current_node.left
            elif current_node.value == value:
                return False
            elif current_node.value > value:
                current_node = current_node.right

        # id(current_node) <-- I need to create a object on this
        current_node = BinarySearchTree(value)  # <--
        # id(current_node) <-- This is a new assigned id, but I need the same as the previous id

        return True

binary_search_tree = BinarySearchTree(2)
binary_search_tree.insert(5)

print(binary_search_tree.__dict__)
```

`current_node` refers to `current_node.left` or `current_node.right`.

I need to create a new object and assign it to the pointer the `current_node` is referring,

but I only create a new object and assign it to a new pointer.

Comment: What does "the pointer the current_node is referring" mean?

Comment: @ScottHunter I am not sure if I meant it right, can you please try my code and tell me, why it doesn't inserting `5`?

Comment: Because by the time `current_node` is `None`, you no longer have any information telling where to assign `value`.  So you either need to save that information before overwriting `current_node`, or make the assignment as soon as you determine where it must go.

Comment: I am not sure if I get it. Can you give me a snippet of your thoughts, please?

Answer (score 0):

> `a new assigned id, but I need the same as the previous id`

After the loop, as Scott Hunter noted, *`current_node` is `None`*, so *`the previous id`* is the “identity” of **`None`**, and you surely understand that *a new object*'s **`id`** cannot be the same as the **`id`** of **`None`**. What you could do is modify the loop in a way which allows to refer to the attribute `left` or `right` afterwards as needed:

```
        while current_node is not None:
            object = current_node   # remember the node to be changed
            if current_node.value < value:
                current_node = current_node.right
                name = 'right'      # remember the attribute to be changed
            elif current_node.value == value:
                return False
            elif current_node.value > value:
                current_node = current_node.left
                name = 'left'       # remember the attribute to be changed
        setattr(object, name, BinarySearchTree(value))  # make the change
```

Alternatively you could make things a bit more simple by replacing in `__init__`

```
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
```

with

```
        self.subtree = [left, right]
```

and the whole body of `insert` with

```
        if value == self.value: return False
        t = 0 if value < self.value else 1
        if self.subtree[t]: return self.subtree[t].insert(value)
        self.subtree[t] = BinarySearchTree(value)
        return True
```